# javascript minify library with support to ES6 classes with private members

Tags: javascript, minify, google-closure-compiler

I'm looking for a library able to minify ES6 modules implementing clases with private members. All I have tried so far, including `Google Closure Compiler`, `uglify-es`, `babel-minify`, fails when they encounter `#stage` or any other member beginning with `#` (they explicitly complains about that character).
For example this won't compile:

```
export default class QuiddisMakePlayer {

    #stage;
    #scormTracker;

    constructor(url, api){
        this.setup(url, api);
    }
   
    setup(){}

}
```

Comment: See an example error on [Google Closure's Compiler](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250Aexport%2520default%2520class%2520QuiddisMakePlayer%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2523scormTracker%253B%250A%257D%250A%250A) `JSC_PARSE_ERROR: Parse error. '}' expected at line 2 character 2
  #scormTracker;`

Comment: AFAIK private field mangling is not supported by babel minify, there is a github issue tracking this:https://github.com/babel/minify/issues/596

Comment: @JuanMendes yes that's exactly what I get!